# Sync Sitecore Item into Dynamics CRM Custom Entity

Tags: data-exchange-framework, dynamics-crm-module

I am trying to sync from Dynamics CRM into Sitecore/Xdb in both ways using Dynamics CRM 2.0.1

I can do next sync:

1. Dynamics CRM to xDb
2. xDb to Dynamics CRM Contacts
3. Dynamics CRM entity to Sitecore items.

I have to sync Sitecore items into Dynamics CRM Entity.

I created next pipeline steps :

[image]

When I sync I receive next message :

```
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: Product Registration Item to CRM Product Registration)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] 3 match(es) found. (pipeline: Read Products Registration from Sitecore, pipeline step: Read Sitecore Items Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: bb522002-21c1-43ba-89a0-9bce2f9ba9a5)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Cannot resolve entity from location or entity model is null. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: f5eda1e1-b153-42ce-a024-22bbc6f47b8f)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, completed pipeline steps: 3)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Cannot resolve entity from location or entity model is null. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: f5eda1e1-b153-42ce-a024-22bbc6f47b8f)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, completed pipeline steps: 3)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Cannot resolve entity from location or entity model is null. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: f5eda1e1-b153-42ce-a024-22bbc6f47b8f)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Products Registration Items to Product Crm Entity, pipeline step: Add Dynamics Product Registration to Queue Pipeline Step, completed pipeline steps: 3)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] 3 elements were iterated. (pipeline: Read Products Registration from Sitecore, pipeline step: Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: 9d137a68-dda1-44a5-a494-4956ebfe0ebc)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline processor finished processing pipeline steps. (pipeline: Read Products Registration from Sitecore, pipeline step: Iterate Data and Run Pipelines Pipeline Step, completed pipeline steps: 2)
ManagedPoolThread #9 10:44:23 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline batch processor finished processing pipelines. (pipeline batch: Product Registration Item to CRM Product Registration, completed pipelines: 1)
```

What am I missing, entities are not created into Dynamics CRM ?

Comment: It says that "cannot resolve entity from location ...". Double check if the resolver configured carefully.

Comment: And I see you are adding product to a queue but I do not see where the queue created/registered.

Comment: Yep, I guess I am missing something. we can discuss on slack if you are available

Comment: I added Create Entity queue and I have same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed 2 pipeline steps.

- **Create Entity Queue** - before add an entity to a queue you need to create queue.
- **Submit Remaining Entities From Queue** - checks if there are some entities in the queue after iterating and submit all of them.
- **Add Entity to Queue Pipeline Step** - adds entity to the queue but also can submit entities if its count in the queue equivalent batch size.

[image]